# Knn for name matching-unsupervised learning

Tags: python, knn

I am working on a name matching problem using synthetic data such as

```
alertname   custname
0   wlison  wilson
1   dais    said
2   4dams   adams
3   ad4ms   adams
4   ad48s   adams
5   smyth   smith
6   smythe  smith
7   gillan  gillan
8   gilen   gillan
9   scott-smith scottsmith
10  scott smith scottsmith
11  perrson person
12  persson person
```

Now I want to apply Knn for this task in unsupervised way, since I do not have any explicit label. I want to output matching score for each of the rows. I have used fuzzy matching already, now just wanted to explore knn for some automation. Would really appreciate if someone can provide starting point. Having said that, we do not have external label here.

Comment: You cannot KNN is a supervised learning technique. You can try K-means clustering for it

Comment: I have already explored that. It seems people have applied Knn in unsupervised way. Even the scikit library documentation suggests that Knn can be used for unsupervised learning. Please be sure before commenting something.